# Hyperref and splitindex donot work if the pagenumber is to be bold

Tags: hyperref, splitidx

I have the following MWE test.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\newindex[Wissenschaftliche Namen]{sci}
\newindex[Deutsche Namen]{dt}
\newcommand{\BTS}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1\sindex[sci]{#1|textbf}}}} %Index Scientific
\newcommand{\BTD}[1]{#1\sindex[dt]{#1}} %Index deutsch
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\BTS{Thymelicus lineola} (\BTD{Schwarzkolbiger Braun-Dickkopffalter}

    \printindex*

\end{document}
```

Compiled with pdflatex and splitindex the test-sci.idx shows

```
\indexentry{Thymelicus lineola|textbf}{1}
```

i.e the hyperpage attribute is not present as is in the test-dt.idx:

```
\indexentry{Schwarzkolbiger Braun-Dickkopffalter|hyperpage}{1}
```

Any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new command which combines \textbf and \hyperpage:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{splitidx,xparse}
\newindex[Wissenschaftliche Namen]{sci}
\newindex[Deutsche Namen]{dt}
\NewDocumentCommand\boldhyperpage{ m } {\textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}}
\newcommand{\BTS}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1\sindex[sci]{#1|boldhyperpage}}}} %Index Scientific
\newcommand{\BTD}[1]{#1\sindex[dt]{#1}} %Index deutsch
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\BTS{Thymelicus lineola} (\BTD{Schwarzkolbiger Braun-Dickkopffalter}

    \printindex*

\end{document}
```